# Gradle Build blocked on :app:mergeDebugResources

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm making an Android app and everything was working perfectly until this morning. After some change in my code, Gradle won't build anymore my project, it is blocked on `:app:mergeDebugResources`.
I've been waiting for 20min but nothing..

Any idea ?

Here is the complete gradle console :

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to /Users/yohannmbp/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

:app:buildInfoDebugLoader
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportConstraintConstraintLayout102Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComGetkeepsafeRelinkerRelinker122Library
:app:prepareComGithubBartekscAndroidPdfViewer261Library
:app:prepareComGithubBartekscPdfiumAndroid150Library
:app:prepareIoRealmRealmAndroidLibrary340Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
```

The app gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mous.improov_flash"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.6.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

And the project gradle file :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
        classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.4.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: have you tried restarting your computer and trying it again?

Comment: @Jonathan727 yes I tried multiple times but still the same problem...

Comment: What happens if you run `gradlew.bat assembleRelease` from a command line in your project directory?

Comment: Now blocking at `:app:mergeReleaseResources`, here is the complete output : [link](https://pastebin.com/0bvUDH9q)

Comment: Is your CPU or disk at 100% while it is blocked?

Comment: No seems not, my cpu usage is around 30%, don't know about the disk but doesn't seems to be at 100% (I'm on a mac with only ssd, I can't find a percentage of disk use)

Comment: You are using a dynamic specification in your support library version. This is not recommended as it makes your builds nondeterministic. I'd try specifying `25.4.0`, `26.0.0-beta1` or `26.0.0-beta2` to see if any of those fix it.

Comment: I solved the problem by restarting a new project but I got the problem again and I can't start a new one, I've got too many classes. I tried specifying the support library version but it's still the same..

Comment: Well, I solved the problem again just by copying the folder of my project in a new folder...